# replacing "=" of encoded string in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, replace, base64

I have a Text Which is being encoded using base64 
For example I have a String

```
string = "Hello"
```

It is encoded

```
Encoded string is :"SGVsbG9XQ1Q="
```

and then prepend the string with "||" (2-Pipe Character)

Now problem is I want to replace all `=` in that encoded string with `|` (one pipe) only at end of strings not in middle of any string

How will I replace all `=` only at end of the String with `|` in qt c++?

Here is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

QString base64_encode(QString string);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString srcString = "HelloWCT";
    QString encodedString = base64_encode(srcString);

    qDebug() << "Encoded string is" << encodedString;
    return a.exec();
 }

 QString base64_encode(QString string){
 QByteArray ba;
 ba = ba.append(string);
 ba = ba.toBase64();
 ba = ba.prepend("||");
 return(ba);
}
```

How to apply my replacing logic only at end of string?can anybody help me with the logic?

I have logic but dont know how to apply it?

Logic is: it will start checking from end of string if there is "=" it will replace it with "|" and it wil gain check if there exist another "=" before the last equal to it will again replace and then if before second "=" if there is another character it will stop replacing  how can we do this ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `if(ba.endsWith('=')) ba[ba.length()-1] = '|';` ?

Comment: @Mike yes some what like this , but what i want is When it finds any other character then "=" it should stop replacing it ?Can this be done with above method . Acoording to me if(ba.endsWith('=')) ba[ba.length()-1] = '|'; will only replace last "="  what if i have one more "=" at end  of string? will this work?  I have added my logic above? but not aware how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `QByteArray` from the end to the beginning (and break the loop when you find a character other than `'='`), replacing every occurrence of `'='` by a `'|'`, something like this:

```
QByteArray ba("SGVsbG9XQ1Q=");
for(int i=ba.length()-1; i>=0 && ba[i]=='='; i--)
    ba[i] = '|';
```

Comment: rbegin() is not a member of Qbyte array? can we use begin and end instead

Comment: @cyley , see my edited answer. **[`rbegin`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#rbegin) is a member of `QByteArray`**. However, it was introduced in Qt 5.6 (looks like you are using a version older than that).

Comment: yes I have found the solution thanks for the help. I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the exact solution:

```
for(int i=ba.length()-1; i>=0 ;i--)
         if(ba.at(i) == '=')
         {
            //replace with "|"
            ba.replace(i,1,QByteArray("|"));
         }
        else
           break;
```

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: I just posted my answer here